# loading achievements from GameKit always returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

I have a set of achievements regisgtered in iTunes connect.  They are displayed on the game center UI along with the leader board.  However, I am unable to load the achievement data from game center when I start up my app.  In the following code snippet, the "achievements" NSArray is always 'nil'.  Note that there is also *no* error.  Thanks in advance!

```
[GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *achievements, NSError *error)

    {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            for (GKAchievement* achievement in achievements)
                [achievementsDictionary setObject: achievement forKey: achievement.identifier];
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting the data that describes the achievements (the stuff entered into iTunes Connect), then you want [loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievementDescription_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKAchievementDescription/loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler%3a).  If you want the current player's achievements then your code should work, but if the player has no achievements you will get nil (rather than array of uncompleted achievements).

Comment: Thanks Lewis!  Your comment made me realize what my problem was.  It was a silly mistake unrelated to the code itself.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Lewis Hi Lewis! I am kinda new to GC. I am also trying loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler which comes out to be nil even if i repeatedly report a completed achievement. Any ideas?